# when T updates in an ObservableCollection<T>, recommendation for refreshing other dependent properties

Tags: wpf

In MVVM, what's intend technique to refresh property NumberOfAdults and NumberOfChildren to be updated on the UI? More generally speaking, how does the People view model catch updates and refresh the properties that depend on contents on `OberservableCollection<Person>`?

The solution requires more advanced usage of the XAML binding syntax. What is it?

**The Person view model**

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Age"); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

**The People View Model**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class PeopleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Happy", Age = 12 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Sleepy", Age = 15 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Sneezy", Age = 17 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Grumpy", Age = 45 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Dopey", Age = 50 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Bashful", Age = 60 });
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "Doc", Age = 75 });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people;}
        set { _people = value;}
    }

    public int NumberOfAdults
    {
        get 
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Person p in People)
            {
                if (p.Age >= 18)
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }

    public int NumberOfChildren
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Person p in People)
            {
                if (p.Age < 18)
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }

    }
}
```

**The Main XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=NumberOfAdults}"></Label>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=NumberOfChildren}"></Label>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}"></DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hook to propertyChanged for `Person` in your ViewModel class and raise propertyChanged from there for dependent properties.

Comment: Perhaps I am misinterpreting your comment, but it seems like this would increase the coupling between the view models.

Comment: `Person` is a model class i suppose and not a ViewModel class. And referring to Model class from ViewModel class is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you are following MVVM, I will suggest that you should have a PeopleCollection as Model class with two properties, NumberOfAdults and NumberOdChildrens. Its not a duty of a ViewModel to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. It's not great but will work. I implement a callback against the ObservableCollection on CollectionChanged event. In it's callback I register the PropertyChanged event.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class PeopleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        People.CollectionChanged += People_CollectionChanged;

        // Same as before....
    }

    void p_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = (Person)sender;
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Update occured on Name: {0} Age: {1}",p.Name,p.Age));

        NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfAdults");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NumberOfChildren");
    }

    void People_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("People_CollectionChanged called.");
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Person p in e.NewItems)
            {
                p.PropertyChanged += p_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Person p in e.OldItems)
            {
                p.PropertyChanged -= p_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

    }

    // Same as before.
}
```